# Are conformal maps determined by a finite number of points?

Tags: complex-analysis

For linear fractional transformations, it suffices to specify where three points are mapped to. I am wondering if some analogue of this holds for general conformal mappings.

Answer (score 3):

No. For any finite collection of points $\zeta_1$, $\zeta_2$, ..., $\zeta_N$ in the disc of radius  $1$, consider the map 
$$z \mapsto z+\epsilon \prod(z-\zeta_i).$$
This is a holomorphic map fixing all the $\zeta_i$ and, if $\epsilon$ is small enough, it is conformal.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the group of conformal automorphisms that your region admits. E.g., the Riemann sphere admits a triply transitive group of conformal automorphisms, so you can prescribe the images of three arbitrary chosen points. If your region is the unit disc $D$ then the group of conformal automorphisms has "three real degrees of freedom". This means that you can prescribe, e.g., $f(0)\in D$ and $\arg(f'(0))$, but not $f(0)$ and $f({1\over2})$ independently.

Answer (score 0):

It does not hold for general conformal mappings, as the [example by David E Speyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19714/336501) shows.
If your map is conformal on the *whole plane* (which means, it is biholomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$), then the map is a similarity (it preserves the ratio of distances), see [Corollary 2.10.10, Elliptic Partial Differential Equations and Quasiconformal Mappings in the Plane, by  Martin, Astala, and Iwaniec].

As such, your map cannot fix too many points. In particular, if it fixes three points it must be the identity.

As Christian Blatter pointed out, the number of points to fix depends on the group of symmetries.
If you fix one, rotation are allowed. If you fix two, we still have reflections. If you fix three, only the identity remains.